# Is there a way to display my query results as posts with images (Wordpress site)?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

This is a query example:

```
  $posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'product'");
```

This would give us the IDs that we want.

```
[ID] => 2
[ID] => 6
[ID] => 25 and so on..
```

Now I want to display the posts that have these IDs.

Comment: Could you share the table structure?

Comment: I forgot to clarify that this is a Wordpress site and the table is the wp_posts ( ID(pk), post title, post_type, post_parent, post_name, post_status, guid )

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the query to return `post_name` along with the `id`, e.g.:

```
SELECT ID, post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'product';
```

If you want to display post content and it's present in another table then you need to use the `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

to get post Object by ID:

```
$post_7 = get_post( 7 ); 
$title = $post_7->post_title;
```

and Array

```
$post_7 = get_post( 7, ARRAY_A );
$title = $post_7['post_title'];
```